# google analytics events on links fail on Chrome

Tags: google-analytics

I am installing google analytics on some  links

```
javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'browse', '/hair'])

here's how the link is
<a onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'browse', '/hair'])" href="/hair"><i class="icon-"></i>Hair (162)</a>
```

if I click on the link the push event is not getting recorded.

If I hit the same code from the console then the event is recorded.

NOTE: on Firefox the event are getting recorded properly. So far this only happens on Chrome! :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need the "javascript:" bit only if you put the js in the href attribute (as a protocol designation of sorts). For a click event the javascript method itself will suffice, so your example should look:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'browse', '/hair'])" href="/hair"><i class="icon-"></i>Hair (162)</a>
```

I'm taking a quite educated guess here that FF is more forgiving with the irregular syntax than Chrome. Maybe you can look at the Chrome developer console if this throws an error (or simply fix it and see if things improve).